# Codenameone blackberry devicePin

Tags: blackberry, codenameone

How do I get the BlackBerry device Pin using the codenameone API?

I tried the following:

```
Display.getInstance().getUdid();
```

returns a null pointer.

Is there way to use the DeviceInfo class from rim to work with codenameone or another way to identify a device?

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use the native interfaces to get to that. You can open an RFE in the issue tracker, it sounds like an API we can probably add.

Comment: What issue tracker? Who is 'we' ?

Comment: Codename One team, our issue tracker is here: http://code.google.com/p/codenameone/issues/list